# MVC Validation on Production Site Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, controller

On Localhost my Validation for a user's billing address works, before its submitted. Once I pushed the project to production. Validation does not initiate and I receive the following error ["Sequence Contains no Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90vUk.png). It points back to my Controller "model.Address = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId).Single();".

[Screenshot of the code causing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQUWO.png)

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AcceptSMS)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsActive)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastLoginDate)

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddressId)

<div class="editor-label">
    Name
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mobile)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mobile)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Mobile)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "male") male
    @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "female") female
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressId, "Address")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AddressId)
</div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile model)
    {
         model.Address = db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId);

        // check to verify that the phone number length is correct
        // (when using an input mask, this shouldn't be a problem)
        if (model.Phone.Length != 14)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "please enter a valid phone number");
        }

        if (model.Mobile != null && model.Mobile.Length != 14)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "please enter a valid mobile number");
        }

        // checks to make sure the user is 18 years old
        if (model.DateOfBirth.Date > DateTime.Now.AddHours(2).Date.AddYears(-18))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "you must be at least 18 years of age");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("MyAccount", "Account");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Model

```
namespace XYZ.Models.Domain
{public class UserProfileMetadata
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your first name")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your last name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter a phone number")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter a mobile number")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select a gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select an activation status")]
    [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error can be thrown by `model.Address = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId).Single();` - you should use `.FirstOrDefault()` if there is a chance there is not exactly one matching item

Comment: The fact it works on your localhost and not a production environment makes me think it may be a deployment issue. Can you validate that all of your files uploaded properly? I'm thinking a javascript file may have been missed during deployment.

Comment: And the code you have shown will never save anything. Your `ModelState.AddModelError("", "please enter a billing address");` adds a `ModelState` error so `if (ModelState.IsValid)` always returns false and the view is always returned.

Comment: Thank You for taking time out to answer me question. @Chad I logged onto the Host File Manager and all files have been pushed. Cleared cache, and included the change Stephen Muecke suggested ".FirstOrDefault()" . Still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're seeing error thrown here:

```
model.Address = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId).Single();
```

Try .SingleOrDefault().

Also check if db.Addresses is not empty

```
if (model.Address != null && db.Addresses.Any())
```

EDIT: try this

```
model.Address = db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId);
```

EDIT2: only assign model.Address with existing address if it's not a new address:

```
if (model.AddressId != null && db.Addresses.Any(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId))
    model.Address = db.Addresses.First(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId);
```

Comment: Yes, I have updated the line and tried both ".SingleOrDefault()" and ".FirstOrDefault()". No success. The field for this line is nullable in the database.

Comment: Can you check if there's any data in db.Addresses by doing db.Addresses.Any() in the first IF statement?

Comment: I changed the if statement to "if (model.Address != null && db.Addresses.Any())", pushed to production. The server error still exist and point to the same line. Validation works for all the other fields.

Comment: @Kane Updated the answer. You can try FirstOrDefault(), instead of Where(). Doing a Where and then Single is kind of redundant. If you are enforcing that there's only one address per AddressId, then you can do SingleOrDefault() rather than FirstOrDefault().

Comment: I checked the database there are 5 addresses stored in the database

Comment: So I decided to add the "Address" field to the View. Validation works... I entered in address clicked save and the same server error displays. Could there be something wrong with saving the information to the Database?

Comment: @jordan831 I also tried "model.Address = db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId);"

Comment: With that, does it throw the same "Sequence contains no element" error?

Comment: Yes the same error and line. Trying all I can. The way its set up is that there are two users. Contractors and Clients. Both can pass general information, but the address has its own view and controller accepting city, state, zip ect... I've tried wiring up those necessary fields into the User edit view, but same error "Sequence Contains on Element" on the same line. Thank you for hanging in there and helping me along the way.

Comment: So, when you save a new address, the error occurs on the line "model.Address = db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.AddressId == model.AddressId);? If you are adding a new address, model.AddressId would not have any value. Would it?

Comment: Yes, the error occurs on that line. Inside the database, the AddressId is set to auto increment when a new address is added. If I manually enter in the address information in the database updating and submitting the users information works without any issues as long an Address already exist.

Comment: If you are validating if the address already exists on a new address, that line will fail because it always returns null. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thank you joordan831. Your last post seems to have taken care of that conflict. Sadly I have another server error to chase down right after it. But the exact server error the post was asking about has been resolved. Thanks Again